# Ubuntu suddenly doesn't detect my Monitor anymore

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, xrandr

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad P53 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed and it is connected to an additional Monitor. I connected these devices with a cable that has usb-c on the one side (plugged into my laptop) and HDMI on the other side (plugged into my monitor). Because my ThinkPad has a 4K-resolution and my Monitor has normal HD, I used the command `xrandr --output DP-4 --scale 2x2` so that I can use both screens at the same time without them looking weird and it always worked perfectly fine.

A few days ago, I wanted to work on my Windows Computer, which is also connected to the same monitor, so I changed the monitor's input source (to DisplayPort). When I changed it back to HDMI to continue working on my Ubuntu machine, my Monitor told me "No HDMI signal from your device".

I tried all the basic stuff to fix it, such as turning the laptop and monitor on and off, unplugging all cables und putting them back in and I also switched the cable but it didn't help. The monitor doesn't seem to be the problem as other monitors also won't connect.

When I use the command `xrandr --listmonitors` this is what I get as a response:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Monitors: 1

 0: +*default 3840/1016x2160/571+0+0  default
```

I'm pretty new to Linux and don't know how I should fix this problem, any help would be highly appreciated!